# I keep getting email error messages from django project even if ADMINS deactivated

Tags: python, django

I deactivated:

```
#ADMINS = (
#   ('Me', 'myemail@googlemail.com'),
#)
```

but I still keep getting 500 error messages from my django project. since I have django 1.7, Loggers is not in settings per default. 
this is the last part of email:

```
'SERVER_NAME': 'mysite.com',  
'SERVER_PORT': '80', 
'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',  
'UWSGI_SCHEME': 'http',  
'uwsgi.node': 'server2.mysite.com', 
'uwsgi.version': '2.0.10',  
'wsgi.errors': <open file 'wsgi_errors', mode 'w' at 0x19c8270>,  'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in function uwsgi_sendfile>,  
'wsgi.input': <newrelic.api.web_transaction._WSGIInputWrapper object at 0x41f6f90>, 
'wsgi.multiprocess': True,  
'wsgi.multithread': False, 
'wsgi.run_once': False,  
'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',  
'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}
```

where can these emails be coming from? may be from newrelic?

```
'wsgi.input': <newrelic.api.web_transaction._WSGIInputWrapper object at 0x41f6f90>,
```

Comment: have you tried reloading or restarting your web server?

Comment: @RodXavier yes, I did ``touch conf/uwsgi.ini``

Comment: `touch conf/uwsgi.ini` won't restart your server...